# Проверка подключения к WiFi

Tags: android

Каким образом можно проверить, подключено ли устройство к какой-либо wifi-сети или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверка наличия интернета

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        //we are connected to a network
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
boolean isWifiConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();
```

Не забудьте про разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```